# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I trying to build a simple appplication in .net core, I think I configurated everything correct. Does anyone know what kind of DI error is this, everytime I called http://localhost:61158/api/customer/1 :

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Application.Core.Interfaces.Customers.ICustomerAppService' while attempting to activate 'Application.WebApi.Controllers.Customers.CustomerController'.
```

Startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        //ApplicationServices
        services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService>(sp => sp.GetService<CustomerAppService>());
    }
```

CustomerController.cs:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{

    private readonly ICustomerAppService _customerAppService;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerAppService customerAppService)
    {
        _customerAppService = customerAppService;
    }

    // GET: api/customer/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public CustomerDto Get(int id)
    {
        return _customerAppService.GetCustomerById(id);
    }
}
```

CustomerAppService.cs:

```
public class CustomerAppService : ICustomerAppService
{

    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;

    public CustomerAppService(IRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public CustomerDto GetCustomerById(int id)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(_customerRepository.GetById(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService, CustomerAppService>();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to register **IRepository** inside your **CustomerAppService**

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService, CustomerAppService>();
```

Comment: This is actually correct but not the cause of the error shown. My answer will fix the current problem which will then throw another one which yours will fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered `CustomerAppService`? If not your registration in `ConfigureServices` should probably be as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService, CustomerAppService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an odd line in your startup:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService>(sp => sp.GetService<CustomerAppService>());
```

This line says "whenever I get asked for a `ICustomerAppService` object, use the container to resolve a `CustomerAppService` object" but since you haven't specified the concrete class, it won't work. Instead just do this:

```
services.AddScoped<ICustomerAppService, CustomerAppService>();
```

Comment: Yeah, I did it. Now, I getting this error:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Application.Core.Interfaces.IRepository`1[iNail.DataAccess.Customers.Customer]' while attempting to activate 'Application.Core.Services.Customers.CustomerAppService'.